# Error when Reading from XML file

Tags: c#, xml

i have an XML file like this

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <conStr>
  <server>192.168.1.25;</server> 
  <initial_catalog>chargdb;</initial_catalog> 
  <uid>sa;</uid> 
  <pwd>1;</pwd> 
  </conStr>
```

and i'm using this code for fetch data from this file :

```
        XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
        xd.Load(Application.StartupPath + @"\cng.xml");
        string conStr = string.Empty;
        conStr += "server=";
        conStr +=xd.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["server"].Value;
        conStr += "initial catalog=";
        conStr += xd.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["initial_catalog"].Value;
        conStr += "uid=";
        conStr += xd.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["uid"].Value;
        conStr += "pwd=";
        conStr += xd.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["pwd"].Value;
        MessageBox.Show(conStr);
```

but each time i give an error message like this: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." 
please help me, what can i do to read my file? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your existing code is looking for *attributes* within the `<server>` element. That's not going to work, as you should be looking for *elements* within the root element.

I would make two changes:

- Use LINQ to XML to fetch the values
- Build the connection string using `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` instead of as a string

So something like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(...);
var root = doc.Root;
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    DataSource = root.Element("server").Value,
    InitialCatalog = root.Element("initial_catalog").Value,
    UserID = root.Element("uid").Value,
    Password = root.Element("pwd").Value
};
var connectionString = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: If you only have a single connection configuration, I think that is the best answer!

Comment: @JFTxJ: If there are multiple configurations, I'd use basically the same code - just extracting the bit which creates the connection string to a method accepting an `XElement`.

Comment: @Jon excellent answer, however the XML file needs to be changed to omit the extra semicolons `;`

Answer (score 2):

`xd.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0]` refers to `<conStr>` element. You need to look at it's children.

Consider using [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) to get navigate the document.

Comment: No, `xd.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0]` refers to the `<server>` element. I've just tried this in a test app to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

To properly answer your question, this is what Jakub means:

```
        string conStr = string.Empty; 
        conStr += "server=";
        conStr += xd.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("./server").InnerText;
        conStr += "initial catalog=";
        conStr += xd.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("./initial_catalog").InnerText;
        conStr += "uid=";
        conStr += xd.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("./uid").InnerText; 
        conStr += "pwd=";
        conStr += xd.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("./pwd").InnerText; 

        MessageBox.Show(conStr);
```

And for the record Jakub, xd.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0], is the root element ('conStr')...

Comment: No, `xd.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0]` is the `<server>` element.